# how to customize junit test report

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using [maven surefire report plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/index.html) and [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) to run my [Junit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) test cases. I would like to add little more detail to the test case report. In my case I would be executing same test case 10K time with different `identifier`. My test case would look like

```
@RepeatedTest(10000)
  public void test(){
    TestObject testObject = new TestObject("identifier");
    double valueFromFirstSource = FirstClassUnderTest.calculateValue(testObject);
    double valueFromSecondSource = SecondClassUnderTest.calculateValue(testObject);
    assertEquals(valueFromFirstSource,valueFromSecondSource, .000001);
  }
}
```

I would like to add `identifier` , `valueFromFirstSource` and `valueFromSecondSource` in my test report or atleast `identifier` so that I can identify the failed `identifier` and correct the problem with the data associated. I have been looking many option @TestDoc, @JavaDoc but still not able to find a way to include this information in my test report. Please help.